# Contar y agrupar por valor mas frecuente en MongoDB

Tags: base-de-datos, mongodb, datatables, mongoose, mongod

Teniendo un schema como este:

```
[{
id:1, category:['gourmet','mexican','breakfasts'], food:'eggs&Beans'
},
{
id:2, category:['breakfasts'], food:'waffles'
},
{
id:3, category:['mexican','breakfasts'], food:'burrito'
},]
```

Como podria agrupar y contar las categorias con mayor frecuencia para obtener algo como esto:

```
[
{category: 'breakfasts', count:3, foods:['eggs&beans','waffles','burrito']},
{category: 'mexican', count:2, foods:['eggs&beans','burrito']},
{category: 'gourmet', count:1, foods:['eggs&beans']},
]
```

Comment: Recuerda que para poder ayudarte has de mostrar lo que hayas intentado. Por favor revisa [ask] y [mcve]. Saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que deseas es aplicar `groupby` y una vez agrupes, aplicar funciones de agregación para 'sumar' el número de elementos obteniendo `count`, y para hacer un tipo de 'join' o 'merge' en `food`
Con ayuda de [Python MongoDB – $group (aggregation)](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-mongodb-group-aggregation/) obtuve:

Antes de usar `$groupby` dado que `category` contiene un 'array', y quieres agrupar por los elementos no por el 'array' en sí, empleas antes `$unwind`

```js
aux=mycol.aggregate(
    [
        {"$unwind":"$category"}
        ,{
    "$group" : 
        {"_id" : "$category", 
         "count" : {"$sum" : 1},
         "foods" : {"$push" : "$food"}
         }}
    ])
for i in aux:
    print(i)
```

Salida:

```
{'_id': 'breakfasts', 'count': 3, 'foods': ['eggs&Beans', 'waffles', 'burrito']}
{'_id': 'mexican', 'count': 2, 'foods': ['eggs&Beans', 'burrito']}
{'_id': 'gourmet', 'count': 1, 'foods': ['eggs&Beans']}
```

Para obtener "foods" he intentado lo que aplican acá [Merging array fields in MongoDB aggregation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19266590/merging-array-fields-in-mongodb-aggregation).

Otros enlaces que fueron útiles: [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53953185/concat-arrays-using-pymongo-failed-with-unknown-group-operator-concatarrays), [4](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/), [5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54440636/the-field-name-must-be-an-accumulator-object).

Comment: Por algún motivo que desconozco no pude usar 'category' en la salida y lo he dejado como '_id'

Comment: Gracias por responder. Recuerda que el OP debe mostrar que ha realizado algún intento, de lo contrario su pregunta puede terminar cerrada por falta de un [mcve]. Lo cual ocasionaría que tu respuesta no sea visible para el resto de usuarios. Saludos